# Accidentally "Merged remote-tracking branch 'origin/x' into x", how can I remove this completely from my repository?

Tags: github, repository

I accidentally made the same commit twice, and then somehow merged them and now there's this commit called "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/lab1' into lab1" Also my local repository is apparently not synced, this seems simple but I'm stuck

Tried squashing commits into one on github desktop, but it says "Unable to squash. Squashing replays all commits up to the last one required for the squash. A merge commit cannot exist among those commits."

I know how to fix this on my local repository, but how do I remove that merge commit from github?

Answer (score 0):

If that merge commit is the latest one on `lab1`, you can simply reset one commit earlier (make sure you don't have any work in progress):

```
git switch lab1
git reset --hard lab1~
git fetch
git rebase origin/lab1
git push
```

But you have done commits *after* that merge commit, then you need to mark them and replay them:

```
git switch lab1
git branch m <sha1 of the merge commit>
git branch lab1 tmp
git reset --hard m~
git fetch
git rebase origin/lab1
git rebase --onto lab1 m tmp
git switch lab1
git merge tmp
git push
```

---

> Am I to do this all the way back to the commit I want, if I have commits after the commit I want to revert too?

`git branch m <sha1 of the merge commit>` is here to mark the merge commit, after which you have other commits.

- `git reset --hard m~` + git fetch + `git rebase origin/lab1` removes that merge commit '`m`'
- `git rebase --onto lab1 m tmp` will replay all the commit you had *after* that merge commit '`m`' onto the `lbl1` branch

Comment: This works for the local repository but how do I remove the commits from the remote repository on github?

Comment: @Hideharu By pushing your local branch, whose history will replace the remote branch.

Comment: I managed to figure this out, what I had to do is do the reset but skip the fetch command, then do "git push -f" to force update the remote repository.

Comment: @Hideharu Yes, if origin/lab1 already include commits you do not want.